# Can't get the right shape for tf.matmul or tf.squared_difference

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

From a DNA sequence, I one hot encoded every base (A,C,G,T,N) to

```
{'A': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 'C': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 'G': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 'T': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 'N': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Every DNA sequence has 400 bases. So my final training data has a shape `X_train.shape = (111453, 400, 5)` (111453 rows, 400 letters, every letter encoded in a 5 element vector)

My label data is a simple yes/no, so if the DNA sequence has an error it is [1], if not, it is [0], so `Y_train.shape is (111453,1)`

I'm trying to build a small NN with tensorflow.

```
layer_1_nodes = 5
layer_2_nodes = 10
layer_3_nodes = 5
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 5
number_of_outputs = 1

# Input Layer
with tf.variable_scope('input'):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 400, 5), name="X")

# Layer 1
with tf.variable_scope('layer_1'):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights1", shape=[400, 5, layer_1_nodes], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases1", shape=[layer_1_nodes], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    layer_1_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, weights) + biases)


# Layer 2
with tf.variable_scope('layer_2'):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights2", shape=[400, layer_1_nodes, layer_2_nodes], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases2", shape=[layer_2_nodes], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    layer_2_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer_1_output, weights) + biases)

# Layer 3
with tf.variable_scope('layer_3'):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights3", shape=[400, layer_2_nodes, layer_3_nodes], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases3", shape=[layer_3_nodes], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    layer_3_output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer_2_output, weights) + biases)

with tf.variable_scope('layer_drop'):    
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=layer_3_output, rate=0.4)

# Output Layer
with tf.variable_scope('output'):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights4", shape=[400, layer_3_nodes, number_of_outputs], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases4", shape=[number_of_outputs], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    prediction = tf.matmul(dropout, weights) + biases

with tf.variable_scope('cost'):
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name="Y")
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(prediction, Y))
```

But I'm always getting errors regarding to the shape of the tensors. Either the first matmul in layer 1, or the cost squared_difference() `(Incompatible shapes: [400,400,1] <- the prediction tensor vs. [111453,1])`

Tried a model with keras:

```
input_shape = (400, 5, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
```

But I can't get my input shape right.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to do. So for example, for layer 1, you have a weights tensor with shape `(400, 5, 5)`, so like different weights for each position? But then only one `5` biases for the `400` elements. And the same for the rest... instead of `tf.matmul(X, weights)` it could be something like `tf.einsum('nij,ijk->nik', X, weights)` (on each layer)... but then that would leave you with an output of `(?, 400, 1)`, how should that be compared to the single `1` / `0` label per example?

Comment: @jdehesa I chose a smaller number of biases just to get faster feedback if something is not working. Given that I start with a rank 3 tensor, I'll always have a rank 3 output, right? Then how would you usually compare this to a binary label? or is it the model that I'm following completely wrong for my kind of data?

Comment: Well you can consider each `(400, 5)` example as a flat `(2000,)` and then have regular dense layers that end up collapsing to a single neuron, but you can reduce the number of weights (and consequently training time and possibly overfitting) by using other models, for example a recurrent network or convolutions across the length of the sequence. I don't know anything about the domain of your problem, but generally recurrent models are very effective with linear sequences (and I believe there are several published works on their application to DNA sequences).